# Need help adding background image

Tags: html

So I have made a website and I am a beginner so please take a look at my website using GOOGLE CHROME and then tell me why the background image is not appearing. The url is IS.gd/space101 thats all.

Comment: The background image does not exist at the specified URL. The referenced domain appears to have been [suspended](http://www.ehdwalls.com/cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi).

Answer (score 2):

That's because your image is unavailable. See for yourself: http://www.ehdwalls.com/plog-content/images/1920x1200/space/space_travel_remix_by_mx-steel_2560x1600__resized_1920x1200-wide.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats the problem exactly, but there are 2 main issues in my opinion.
1. The URL of the image you like to use referers me to an site which tells me that the website is currently unavailable. Maybe thats the issue.
2. Have a look over your structure. You should use for every website this structure:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>//Content like <title></title></head>
    <body>Content of your website</body>
</html>`
You used multiple `<body>` Tags. Maybe thats also an issue.